# How to add billing Country_id from sales_order_adress in Email Template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, custom-variable, magento2-4-5

I am using Magento Version 2.4.5,  I want to specifically add the country_id (e.g. FR for France) in the order email template.

The variable with the Billing address only returns the full address block.

Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the following code.

```
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getCountry()}} //Get the country’s ID

{{var order.getShippingAddress().getCountryModel().getName()}} //Get the country’s full name

{{var order.getBillingAddress().getCountry()}} //Get the country’s ID
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the code. I don't get an error but I don't get an output either. Its just blank.

Comment: @JkCasi I have updated my answer. Can you try first with the billing then the shipping address?

Comment: I tried all three but none give me an output. When I use {{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}} then i get one.